# Trying to create a list of text elements from an HTML table

Tags: python

I have a table structure like this:

```
<table class="member_sheet_table standard_list_table rwdCompactible rwdTable" data-ftDefaultContimes="1">
    <tbody class="rwdTbody">
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:00 AM</div> 
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:10 AM</div>     
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:20 AM</div>     
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:30 AM</div>
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:40 AM</div>        
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:50 AM</div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to create a list, startTime() like this from the table;

```
startTime(0) = 7:00 AM
startTime(1) = 7:10 AM
startTime(2) = 7:20 AM
...
```

Not having any success. Help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Can you also share what you have done so far so we can review and provide you the right level of help

Comment: If extracting information from HTML is what you want, use Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Step one in having success is trying something. What are you having trouble with? Picking the right data structure to store the result in? Selecting specific elements from html? Loading the html so you can filter it?

Comment: @AyushBasak or lxml and xpath, or Scrapy, or any number of lesser know libraries. There's a reason SO doesn't allow questions that ask for opinions - there's no one best solution for every problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using BeautifulSoup:

```
html = '''<table class="member_sheet_table standard_list_table rwdCompactible rwdTable" data-ftDefaultContimes="1">
    <tbody class="rwdTbody">
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:00 AM</div></td></tr>
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:10 AM</div></td></tr>
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:20 AM</div></td></tr>
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:30 AM</div></td></tr>
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:40 AM</div></td></tr> 
        <tr class="rwdTr" data-ftrowtype=":F"><td class="sT rwdTd"><div class="time_slot">7:50 AM</div></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
'''

# solution using BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

timeslots = [el.text for el in soup.select('table.member_sheet_table > tbody > tr > td > div.time_slot')]

print(timeslots)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the following to get what I needed                                           
    get_source = driver.page_source  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_source, 'html.parser')
    time_pattern = re.compile(r'\s(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))')
    times = time_pattern.findall(soup.get_text())